# Is it possible to have a Autobahn WebSocket Client Register for RPC calls?

Tags: python, autobahn, wamp-protocol

Using autobahn, python and WAMP, is it possible for the WebSocket *client* to register for RPC calls - basically function as both a client and a server at the same time?

For example, a "chat client" connects to a "chat server" on a known WS URI/port and establishes a session. The client sends messages and receives responses as normal over this web socket. Then, periodically, the server, over the *same* web socket, issues a random RPC call (via WAMP) against the client requesting the answer to a particular question.

the client, in pseudo code would be doing something like:

```
onMessage(...)
    if simple message
       display message to user
    else
       if rpc call request
          perform command as requested
          send response back to server
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible: WAMP calls that feature "symmetric RPC" or "reverse RPC". It's still in the cooking/experimental, but here is a complete working [example](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp1/rpc/symmetric) with AutobahnPython.

Comment: Symmetric RPC is now in the latest AutobahnPython release 0.6.3: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autobahn

Comment: It seems that the symmetric RPC example was removed in [7b9079f](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/commit/7b9079fb6c2fa523710d732a63306afb378df45b#diff-ceb162208a987252d271111f0eb13cd2), but [oberstet suggested to switch](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/issues/262#issuecomment-117188465) to [WAMP2 routed RPC](http://wamp.ws/why/#unified_routing)